# GNU R:Use sapply on sapply

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have a list of statuses. Each list element contains the status of a sensor for every minute of a day (1440 entries, 0 or 1). The list contains all sensors.

For example, `statuses[[3]]` gives a vector with 1440 entries, containing all the 0's and 1's of each minute.

The statuses of all sensors in, let's say, minute 800 is:

```
sapply(statuses,'[',800)
```

I'd like to get the number of active sensors (i.e. showing 1) per minute. How do I do that? Somehow one has to put another `sapply()`around this...

The solution using a for loop would look like this

```
status_ones <- rep(0,1440)
for (k in 1:1440){
  status_ones[k] <- sum(sapply(statuses,'[',k))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me there are several ways to accomplish what you want; this is what jumped out at me first: Since the length of each element of the list is the same, you can treat it as a data frame and use apply. I illustrate this approach below using simulated data that I believe matches your description of your data (this would be for five observations of three sensors):

```
set.seed(42)
statuses <- lapply(1:3, function(x) sample(0:1, 5, replace=TRUE))
statuses
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1 0 1 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 1 0 1 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0 1 1 0 0
status_ones <- apply(as.data.frame(statuses), 1, sum)
status_ones
# [1] 2 3 1 2 2
```

You can easily manually confirm this gives the result you want with this small example. Below you can see the speed benefit of this approach relative to the `for` loop approach or using `sapply` on `sapply` -- I created a larger sample (1440 observations each for three sensors) and used `benchmark` to see  the speed differences:

```
library(rbenchmark)
statuses <- lapply(1:3, function(x) sample(0:1, 1440, replace=TRUE))
benchmark(apply=apply(as.data.frame(statuses), 1, sum),
          sapply=sapply(1:1440, function(x) sum(sapply(statuses, '[', x))),
          loop=for ( i in 1:1440 ) { sum(sapply(statuses, '[', i)) },
          columns=c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative', 'user.self'),
          order='relative')
    test elapsed relative user.self
1  apply   0.883    1.000     0.660
2 sapply   6.115    6.925     5.616
3   loop   6.305    7.140     5.776
```